# Failed to recompile android resource files error when building for android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When building the following project for android, I get the error bellow.

https://github.com/sableangle/Unity2Arduino-Android-Plugin

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to recompile android resource files. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javac.exe -bootclasspath "E:/software/tools_r25.2.3-windows\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -d "E:\software\unity\Unity2Arduino-Android-Plugin-master\Unity_Project\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 ".resources\R.java" "com\unity\plugin\R.java"

stderr[
.resources\R.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
package .resources;
       ^
1 error
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg, Int32 retriesOnFailure)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

My jdk version in Preferences>External tools is jdk1.8.0_111.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when an android library is failing to compile. A jar or aar file.
You can debug this problem by removing the last jar you added and see if the build is successful without it, if it is then that's the problematic jar.

In this case it's the blue.jar file under Assets/Plugins/Android

You probably need to re-export that jar using Eclipse.